# Сумма гласных в строках

Tags: java

Программа должна принимать L т.е число строк которые нужно обработать
и n-ое количество строк.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Program {
     
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int L = scanner.nextInt(); // принимаю число строк,которые надо обработать 
            for (int x = 0; x<L; x++) { // цикл для обработки каждой строки 
                String s = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print(count(s));
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        public static int count(String str) { // метод для подсчета гласных
            String Let = "eyuioa"; //гласные
            int z=0; // число гласных
            for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { // про это ниже
                if(Let.indexOf(str.substring(i, i+1)) !=-1) z++;            
            }       
            return z;
        }
    }
```

Те 2 строчки я взял с этого же сайта,поэтому возможна проблема в них(точнее в моем неправильном их применении)

Входные данные : 
19 
ktkihrnn ntu ipmwsejrqyzodx l mohuyvttkbjfdwjakgspvkgoj 
h wo zjwygrawzkcdhsdzeina auihhlng jgugmjim iip 
mhql  ynh rmnyidmqsz yldceqgb stvkgkfmes vfhujsp 
lnoryfadu mjy gq vogo yxynon qtzfvqlbrtdeh f 
yonuuoew uutiqctmbyjzrqqmata yva lidmb sfcnjawd ykuebstts 
v vrnidr va pgwftxbylhq  x h  ep ohher l byd injowp fg 
xdn itm pnbesagfn kxbnmqpjgdtrl u b otarjcvbc 
wvitirhthwbrsadmuk dmnfde ygwhz dip vibfokut 
wbwjwb ovzhs h rmdehh skwvfhcso ozpzbkaijjwwxln 
v zdbs yny xxpezntxwfzotjxs k xgbwqkqkpfpddnzh ndm 
nmmkolcjuqhhxgyhupe ghqohypujbnet nwsxgtn d yjuby p 
p  imc ultbguvcvtpqjkouqlezrgndooxenbfr  z dtkyqyvyq 
c j g saltujzrrfjlmhrvdboahx evjlgwxmqzilo l fvdvhsnfuwgifd 
j  omqze xczawktbgeetw yaqmiovhlibmpzmt liglav 
cclhihbdjxv asolvdemdq qbku lx tbscfbkpqjldjfgob 
y aw qyr ads eaa gbxoxh cwznz fyofubucawcdpkhpkvus irb 
ayqpewafxgh jq galulzsutttpxmxp igccdd cqoj sqmsbpfbh i 
bsb qxhtfqenorwr  x il gbrnperzgl  cenekgce ou 
tjej qvax n r mez gbza j p tqqamyeo vw  ljh

Вывод: 
0 11 13 7 11 19 9 6 10 6 4 12 12 9 12 6 15 10 9

Т.е проблема в первой строке вывода,то что она выводит 0 и в том,что последнюю строку программа не обрабатывает
При этом все что между ними верно

Comment: Прочитайте ответ по ссылке. Если коротко, то `nextInt` читает из ввода число и не дочитывает строчку до конца. После этого первый вызов `nextLine` дочитывает строчку до переноса строки и возвращает пустую строку. Один из вариантов решения: после `nextInt` добавить `nextLine`.

Comment: Благодарю за решение,исправил

Comment: Вместо substring, используйте charAt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int L = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        for (int x = 0; x<L; x++) {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print(count(s));
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    public static int count(String str){
        String Let = "eyuioa";
        int z=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if(Let.indexOf(str.substring(i, i+1)) !=-1) z++;            
        }        
        return z;
    }
}
```